# Cypress cy.contain(selector, RegExp) not finding expected match

Tags: cypress

I am trying to use `cy.contains` to select an element that has a child element that contains specific text. This is the HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="style-name">
            <div class="name">My_Name_Here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is select the `.row` that contains `My_Name_Here`. I thought I could do so using `cy.contains('.row', /^My_Name_Here$/)`, but this yields nothing. If I change it to `cy.contains('.row', /My_Name_Here/)` then I get the correct element. If I instead do `cy.contains('.name', /^My_Name_Here$/)` I get the `.name` element. Why won't the first regex work? How can I select the `.row` based on the text a child element contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @gear4 said - the nested elements are contributing whitespace to the text of `div.row`.

If you run this you will see the exact text has linefeeds before and after

```js
cy.get('.row')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => console.log(text))
```

You can improve your regex and still get an exact match on non-whitespace text

```js
cy.contains('.row', /^\s*My_Name_Here\s*$/)
```

or you could use the 3rd version and traverse to the `div.row`

```js
cy.contains('.name', /^My_Name_Here$/)
  .parents('.row')
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation: `DOM elements can contain more than the desired text and still match`

I assume that because you're using a more general selector, the `^` and `$` regex chars are matching the beginning and end of *that* selector, instead of every child selector. The fact that the more specific selector works further proves my theory.